# How can I rewrite this if-else statement so that it doesn't use a jump?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am not trying to optimize anything, so please don't tell me, that premature optimization is root of all evil. I am trying to solve a problem and I can't find the third solution.

The problem goes like this:

```
if (x)
    y = a;
else
    y = b;
```

`x` can only be 0 or 1. How to write this condition **without a jump?**

One solution, with a data structure, is:

```
int temp[2] = {b, a};
y = temp[x];
```

Another arithmetic solution is:

```
y = x * a + (1 - x) * b;
```

There is supposed to be a third one, a logical solution. Do you know how it looks like? Please give a solution in C.

Comment: You mean without a jump, don't you?

Comment: I think, if we use switch . 
that will not be a jump. 
right ?

Comment: What logical operators do you know in C...?

Comment: @Vivek Goel: a switch statement is still going to be encoded with a jumps

Comment: Vivek Goel: It is, if you are skipping a case you are jumping.

Comment: Yes, I meant without a jump. Sorry for not being careful enough.

Comment: The array solution you posted yourself, is the best one given by far. Don't listen to anyone suggesting a 80 character line containing a majority of all operators in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin the 'best' solution is just to use the if statement as compilers will probably do the right thing.  But that has nothing to do with the question as the OP clearly states this isn't about optimization.  It is more like a trivia problem or puzzle.

Comment: @fsmc I'm aware of that, I made a comment to the OPs question, and not about how you should program in general. I wouldn't dismiss this as a pointless trivia however. There are plenty of tiny CPUs with limited branch distance, where you might want to avoid branching entirely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
y = a ^ ((x - 1U) & (a ^ b));
```

This uses bitwise x-or

Comment: took me a while to wrap my head around this one.  nice :)  XOR IS HERE!

Answer (score 4):

Are you saying you don't want a jump in the *source* code or at the CPU level?

On my compiler

```
int choose(int x, int a, int b)
{
    int y;

    if (x)
        y = a;
    else
        y = b;

    return y;
}
```

compiles to this -

```
test    ecx, ecx
cmovne  r8d, edx
mov eax, r8d
ret 0
```

Although I've written a jump at the C code level there isn't one in the generated machine code as the compiler is able to use a conditional move instruction.

Comment: Seriously, that's not the solution to the problem. It is supposed to stretch your mind a little, not check whether you can use conditional move. As I said, it is not about optimizing anything, but about finding a solution.

Comment: This answer isn't in the spirit of the question

Comment: Ok sorry. well to be honest I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of the question is.  I find it interesting that writing a branch in the source code doesn't necessarily imply a branch in the generated code.

Comment: I'm looking at the question as more of an exercise/puzzle.  This has its purpose even if it is not so practical.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe isn't the best solution, but I think it is the bitwise equivalent without jumps:

```
y = (~(x*UINT_MAX) & a) | (~(1 - x) & b);
```

Comment: If I would ever have to maintain this code I'll hunt you down with a shotgun.

Comment: You wouldn't have to, I'd probably commit suicide.  I already had to edit it twice.

Comment: ...huh? forsvarir's link and http://codepad.org/rirIW5tL both indicate that it doesn't, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: here we go: http://codepad.org/PppSDoQI. You want `y = (~(1-x) & a) | ((~x + 1) & b);`

Comment: I don't want to think of all the implicit integer promotions going on in that expression. The shotgun doesn't sound like a bad idea...

Comment: @forsvarir you're right, i've updated it to work.  But if Chowlett's solution is correct it seems a lot nicer.

Comment: @Chowlett that won't work because when x is zero ~(1-x) leaves the first bit 0 so you cant do odd numbers for a - http://codepad.org/n2WDuP6M

Answer (score 0):

The following code use the trick that, as `x` is either 1 or 0, `x-1` is either 0 or -1 (a.k.a. 0xFFFFFFFF, assuming 32 bit int:s). If `x` is 1, the result of the `&` is zero, so the result is `a`. When `x` is zero, the result of the `&` will be `b-a`, the total result will then be `a+(b-a)` or simply `b`.

```
int test(int x, int a, int b)
{
  return a + ( (((unsigned int)x)-1) & (b - a) );
}
```

On a fictitious micro-controller (without any fancy conditional move instructions) this will result in four instructions:

```
ADD   #-1 R12
SUB   R13, R14
AND   R14, R12
ADD   R13, R12
```

Admittedly, this is very similar to the XOR solution posted by @6502.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the choose function here then?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int choose(unsigned int x, int a, int b)
{
    unsigned int selector = -x;    

    return (a & selector) | (b & ~selector);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", choose(0, 123, 200));
    printf("%d\n", choose(1, 123, 200));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary `?:` operator. It is made for this.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the compiler will translate this into assembly code without a jump. This example removes the jump from the high level code.

Comment: @Thomas, this question is not about assembler. And there is never such guarantee. A C compiler transforms a statement into whatever pleases and that is functionally equivalent. But if the assembler has a conditional assignment it will most likely use that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jens; a ternary operator will do the trick without a jump.

```
y = x ? a : b
```

BTW, there is a sister site, [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), where people ask questions of the nature "How can I solve problem x with the shortest amount of code while maintaining constraint y?"

Comment: There is no guarantee that the compiler will translate this into assembly code without a jump.  This example removes the jump from the high level code.

Comment: Yes, @Thomas Matthews, but at least @nightcracker will not hunt you down. The ternary form has a widely-used optimization that does not use jumps (see http://www.woodmann.com/forum/showthread.php?11172-Compiler-tricks-in-x86-assembly-Ternary-operator-optimization).

Answer (score 0):

For processors that allow conditional execution of statements:

```
y = a;
if (x != 0) y = b;
```

On an ARM processor in 32 bit mode, this should translate into the following pseudo instructions:

```
mov y, a; move a into y.
test x; (or XOR X, X ; to set condition codes)
MOVNZ y, b ; move b into y if condition is non-zero.
```

No jumps involved here, at least at the assembly language level.

*Note:  platform specific solution, may not be valid for processors without conditional instruction execution capabilities.*

Answer (score -1):

```
switch (x) {
   case 1:
      y = a;
      break;
   default:
      y = b;
      break;
}
```

EDIT: the original question said "with jumps" ... not "without"

Comment: @nightcracker... you edited the question and *THEN* down voted my answer.  Gee...thanks.

Comment: dgnorton: Yes, the question had an error, but from the examples and the general purpose of these question it should be obvious he meant without a jump. It was in the question comments too.

Answer (score -3):

EDIT: I misread the question which states that the C code shouldn't use a jump at all.

I think I'd go with

```
y = b;
if (x)
    y = a;
```

If I read the following disassembled code right, there should be only one jump:

```
0000000000400474 <main>:
  400474:   55                      push   %rbp
  400475:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400478:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40047b:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  40047e:   83 7d f4 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
  400482:   74 06                   je     40048a <main+0x16>
  400484:   8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%rbp),%eax
  400487:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  40048a:   c9                      leaveq
  40048b:   c3                      retq
  40048c:   90                      nop
  40048d:   90                      nop
  40048e:   90                      nop
  40048f:   90                      nop
```

Comment: You didn't misread...@nightcracker edited it to say "without" then down voted everyone that answered the original question.

Comment: Awesome :) Well, at least that question made me see a disassembly today.